# Notification plugin not working phonegap 3.0 for iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing an app with phonegap 3.0.0. I need to show the confirm dialog so I added the Notification plugin from phonegap CLI with the following command (as described in [CLI Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface)):

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
```

But now I can't build the project. When I try to build it fails with following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
  CompileC build/CamTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CamTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVNotification.o CamTest/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/CDVNotification.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

When I remove the Notification plugin everything works fine. I've also tried to add the following in my config.xml (CamTest/www/config.xml) to no effect:

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

Please someone tell me how to work with plugins in Phonegap 3.0.0. I am trying it on iphone simulator. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Try running `phonegap local build -d` to get more debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the same problem, but before we added the required lines in `config.xml`. So, the following two step process also mentioned in [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) and [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html) link solved the problem.

1. On the command line

> $ cordova plugin add
>   https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git

2. In project's config.xml

> ```
> <feature name="Notification">
>     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
> </feature>
> ```